# Struct with field that is AbstractVector of another struct

Tags: julia

I would like to define a struct `Mesh` for which one of the fields is some vector-like of `Element` structs. From the Julia performance tips, it seems it would be best to use parametric types and allow `T` to be subtype of `AbstractVector` since in principle the vector-like of `Element` structs could be a vector, static vector, etc. How can I do this?

The below code is my attempt, however this gives an error:

> ERROR: TypeError: in Type{...} expression, expected UnionAll, got a value of type TypeVar

```
struct Element
  value
end

struct Mesh{T :< AbstractVector}
  elements::T{Element}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting this, I played around and think I found a solution (though I'm not sure if this is the most performant solution):

```
struct Element
  value
end 

struct Mesh{T <: AbstractVector{Element}}
  elements::T
end 

e = Vector{Element}(undef, 1)
e[1] = Element(1)
mesh = Mesh{typeof(e)}(e)
```

Comment: It is a solution. You also may be interested in [StructArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StructArrays.jl).